# How to convert Json to xml or Array to xml in cakephp

Tags: xml, json, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to create one xml from JSON string. Can anyone help me out regarding this. Please find my json here.

```
 {"Customer_CreateOnlyResponse":{"Customer_CreateOnlyResult":{"RequestID":"1212","Message":"Successfully created customer","Success":"true","CustomerID":"1212"}}}
```

Thanks for advance help.

Answer (score 0):

At first you can decode your string to array with [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and this array convert to XML with [Xml Core library](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html) with:

Example:

```
$data = array(
    'post' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'Best post',
        'body' => ' ... '
    )
);
$xml = Xml::build($data);
```